# Accessing Class inside Fragment from Adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, class

I have a Fragment Activity which contains two Fragments.  In one of the fragments I have a task class called `HelpfulTask`  I generally access it like this:

```
new HelpfulTask().execute();
```

But I need to access it from inside my adapter which is in a separate class outside of this Fragment activity.

Again, here is layout:

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

     Fragment A {

     }


     Fragment B extends ListFragment {

         class HelpfulTask extends AsyncTask {

            // How do I call/access this from separate Arraydapter?

         }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- access it via an instance of `FragmentA`, like:

```
MainActivity a = ... // get reference to the activity instance
MainActivity.FragmentA fa = a.new FragmentA();
MainActivity.FragmentA.HelpfulTaskextends h = fa.new HelpfulTaskextends();
```

- Declare the inner classes as `static`, so that you can access them in static way (without instances):

```
MainActivity.FragmentA.HelpfulTaskextends h = new MainActivity.FragmentA.HelpfulTaskextends();
```